# Can we change one's genome into the genome of somebody else

Tags: human-biology, dna

If I (grown-up individual and not just an egg after fertilization) wanted your exact genome, would we be able with today's technology to change my genome into yours?

Comment: Do you mean if *all genetic material* in a grown-up person can be modified?

Comment: No, that would be practically impossible with modern technology. The explanation is pretty lengthy, but do you have specific questions or a certain method you were thinking of that could be more concretely addressed?

Comment: that my friend is what we call a future breakthrough and will happen centuries in the future

Comment: @Tusky - The future doesn't necessarily mean centuries from now... the future is also tomorrow ; )

Comment: @gstestso I am trying to save your posts today $\ddot \smile$. I rewrote your post to clarify it. It still is a very introductory question but at least it gets rid of the feeling it gave that your question mixed philosophy and science (the definition of a "person" goes way beyond its DNA and the question of identity is a question of philosophy not biology). Feel free to roll back if you don't like my edits.

Comment: @Gstestso If you think your question has been answered (which is my feeling), then please check the answer you prefer below (same for your other posts). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [3.72x10<sup>13</sup>](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23829164) (37 *trillion*) cells in the average adult human body. It would be essentially impossible to target every single cell just to change a single [base pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_pair), let alone the massive genetic and [epigenetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics) changes that would be necessary to change someone into a clone of another.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go one step further than Matt and say it would be impossible even if we had the technology.

And here is why.

Lymphocytes, B-Cells and T-cells, through V-J and V-D-J joining actually recombine their DNA as they are maturing, they cut out long stretches of DNA, so each and every one of those cells has regions of DNA that are different from every other cell in your body.

Then even when they get selected and go through clonal expansion those regions of DNA go through a process called somatic hypermutation which deletes and replaces nucleotides in the hyper variable regions of those genes, in the hopes of making them better binders.

So you would then have to account for every single one of those unique genomes, and the only way to do that would be to destroy the cells, so in the Biological equivalent of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, the act of observing effects the outcome because you would be changing the other person as well. So you will never ever be able take on the complete genetic make-up of someone else.